# Eclipse StatEt: Content assist in console

Tags: eclipse, console, keyboard-shortcuts, content-assist, statet

Content assist is very helpful but in my setup it currently only works in the Editor. Is it possible to activate content assist in the interactive console?

Please be specific: I have tried to change the 'Content Assist' key binding many times, but it does not seem to have any affect in the console.

Comment: No, Content Assist does not work in the console

Comment: I can't imagine that, I might as well use the good old terminal! Are you sure?

Comment: It was working in some previous versions, but now it doesn't at my sytem neither :(